# User specific properties file in Spark (.hiverc equivalent)

Tags: apache-spark

We are trying to set some additional properties like adding custom built spark listeners, adding jars to driver and executor classpaths etc for each Spark Job getting submitted.

Found below implementations:

1. Change the spark-submit launcher script to add these extra properties
2. Edit the spark-env.sh add add these properties to "**SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS**" and "**SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH**" variables
3. Add a --properties-file option to spark-submit launcher script

Would like to check if this can be done specific to users something like .hiverc in hive instead of doing it at the cluster level. This allows us to perform A/B testing of the features we newly build.